# How to insert the data that is returned from an API in a text format to the Django models

Tags: python, django

I'm using an API (https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/pub/data/weather/uk/climate/datasets/Tmax/date/UK.txt) that returns the data in a text format. so with the data returned I want to add those data in the Django model. so Now I'm stuck with the problem that how should I parse the data in order to add them to the model. Because since the data returned by that API as you can see that the year 2021 doesn't have all the data.

Currently, I have 18 fields in the Django model (each field for each value) and my approach was to extract all the data which has a numerical constant pattern using regex and with the extracted data, I will insert the data into the DB model by iterating it over the list. But the problem is that year 2021 doesn't have all the data and the regex that I'm using is just extracting the numerical values from the string that is returned from the API.

for example:

```
ear    jan    feb    mar    apr    may    jun    jul    aug    sep    oct    nov    dec     win     spr     sum     aut     ann
2021    4.9    7.0    9.8   10.9   13.4   18.7   21.1   18.9   18.7   14.0                  6.21   11.35   19.56
```

code that I've written so far.

```
numeric_const_pattern = '[-+]? (?: (?: \d* \. \d+ ) | (?: \d+ \.? ) )(?: [Ee] [+-]? \d+ ) ?'
rx = re.compile(numeric_const_pattern, re.VERBOSE)

r = requests.get('https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/pub/data/weather/uk/climate/datasets/Tmax/date/UK.txt')

years_data = r.text.split('\n', 6)[6].split('\n')
for year in years_data:
    print(rx.findall(year))
    # here i want to insert the values to the django model.
```

So how should I go ahead with building the logic for this? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: From what I'm seeing, each 'column' is 7 characters long, between the data and the white space for that data, until you get to the 'win' column, at which point they're 8 characters long? The data can be viewed as a table because it's padded with whitespace consistently, so you can use that. Iterate 7 chars, then strip ws.

Comment: what is exactly your problem? you don't know how to create models in or inserting data?

Comment: Seems like a fixed width data table. You can read each line and cut the columns based on the width. Best and easy that using regex.

Comment: @JoseAntonioCastroCastro thank you for the reply. any documentation or article on how to do it will help. Do I need to make use of any libraries like pandas or something or any built-in functionalities are there?

Comment: @MojixCoder the issue i'm facing or i'm unaware of is that since the data which is returned from the API is a text format I'm not sure how to extract them. Because if you look at the response of the API all the rows has data until the year 2021. So currently I'm my approach is extracting all the floating-point values and adding to the model one by one. but in the case of 2021, it's a little unpredictable to extract the values

Comment: @KyleAlm Oh Yes. I didn't notice that. Thank you

Comment: you can split lines. remember to skip the first 5 row. `print(one_line.split())`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a dictionary like `MAP_ROW_TO_FIELDS` to map every field to your position in the x axis.

Then iterate over each row and process the values defined in the dictionary keys, ignoring the empty or invalid positions.

Next, using `setattr` in every key you can set the values directly to the model instance.

```py
import re
import requests


# The key value are the same that the model field names.
# In the tuple the x position of each field (start, end).
MAP_ROW_TO_FIELDS = {
    'year': (0, 5),
    'jan': (6, 11),
    'feb': (12, 19),
    'mar': (20, 26)
    # add others here
}

RE_INT = re.compile('^\d+$') 
RE_FLOAT = re.compile('^\d+\.\d+$') 


url = "https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/pub/data/weather/uk/climate/datasets/Tmax/date/UK.txt"
response = requests.get(url)


line_num = 0
for line in response.text.split('\n'):
    line_num += 1
    if line_num > 6 and line.strip(): # avoid empty lines
        row = RowModel()
        
        for key in MAP_ROW_TO_FIELDS.keys():
            val = line[MAP_ROW_TO_FIELDS[key][0]: MAP_ROW_TO_FIELDS[key][1]]
            val = val.strip()
            # If data match, saves directly to the model.
            if RE_INT.match(val):
                setattr(row, key, int(val))
            elif RE_FLOAT.match(val):
               setattr(row, key, float(val))
            else:
                # print(line)
                print('Unknow value "%s" for field %s' % (val, key))
        
        # Save to database
        row.save()
```

Can easy get the x coordinates opening the text file in a code editor.